# Integral of a max function over a hypersphere; expected max z score

Tags: probability, statistics, integration, manifolds

Is there a closed-form expression for the integral of max($x_1,..., x_n$) over the ($n-2$)-dimensional hypersphere, {$x \in \mathbf{R}^n$:  $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0$,  $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 1$}?

I come across this integral in trying to find the expected value of the maximum  *z* score from independent normals.